# What's the (limit of the) n-th order derivative of this integral?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I met a question that asks me to calculate the result of an integral first:
$$f(s)=\int_0^1e^{-sx}dx,s\geq0\tag1$$
It is easy, if I am not wrong, the answer should be $1$ when $s=0$, and $\frac{1-e^{-s}}s$ for $s>0$.

Then it asks me to calculate the limit:
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{df(s)}{ds}\tag2$$
It is also easy, the derivative is:
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{df(s)}{ds}=\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-s}s-(1-e^{-s})}{s^2}\tag3$$
because it is a $\frac00$ form limit, by using the L'Hôpital law, we can quickly calculate that the limit is $-\frac12$.

However, I got stuck in the final question, it asks me to calculate
$$\lim_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{d^nf(s)}{ds^n}\tag4$$
I tried to calculate the n-th derivative directly first, hoping to find some laws. But as all you can see from (3), it will be only more and more complex as I differentiate (3).

I also tried to use the Leibniz formula, like let $u=1-e^{-s}$ and $v=s^{-1}$, so $f(s)=(1-e^{-s})s^{-1}=uv$, but I still could not get any idea after just writing a long formula. So how can I calculate (4)? Could you give me some hints? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{(n)}(s)=\int_0^{1}(-x)^{n}e^{-sx}dx$. So $\lim_{s \to 0} f^{(n)}(s) =\int_0^{1}(-x)^{n}dx=\frac {(-1)^{n}} {n+1}$

Comment: A wonderful and neat answer! Thank you very much! I guess I should review the basic concept of integral and derivation...

Comment: Dear @Kavi Rama Murthy thank you for answering my question before, but today when I show your method to my friend, he was sparked, too. But then he said that the limit and the derivation work could not be simply exchanged unless it obeys the ... Lebesgue convergence theorem, which I never heard. If you have time, could you tell me your evidence to do it briefly? Thank you.

Comment: @PeterNova Yes, the calculation of derivatives of $f$ by taking the derivatives inside the integral has to be justified using DCT. For the first derivative you can use the fact that $|\frac {e^{(s+h)x}-e^{sx}} h| \leq xe^{sx}$ and $xe^{sx}$ is integrable. For further derivatives  you can use induction and similar inequalities.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, a series expansion and term-wise differentiation of $f(s)$ can be performed:

$$f(s) = \frac{1 - e^{-s}}{s} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^{k-1}}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} \frac{s^k}{k!}.$$  Therefore, $$f^{(n)}(s) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} \frac{s^{k-n}}{(k-n)!}.$$  In all cases, the first term is constant with respect to $s$.  Now the result is trivial:  $$\lim_{s \to 0} f^{(n)}(s) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1} + \lim_{s \to 0} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} \frac{s^{k-n}}{(k-n)!} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}.$$

---

Step by step:  note $$e^s = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{s^k}{k!},$$ hence $$e^{-s} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-s)^k}{k!},$$ and $$1 - e^{-s} = 1 - \left(\frac{(-s)^0}{0!} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^k}{k!}\right) = - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^k}{k!},$$ hence $$\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s} = (-s)^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^{k-1}}{k!}.$$

Comment: Thank you heropup! You give me a precious new view of the question. Till now I come to know the elegance of your answer. But I still have one question, are you using a Taylor expansion or say the Maclaurin formula when transforming:  $f(s) = \frac{1 - e^{-s}}{s} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-s)^{k-1}}{k!}$ , and just make an expansion for the upper term, right?

Comment: @PeterNova See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! It taught me a big lesson to solve the questions like this.